# Using PHP parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a parameter of PHP of $test1, I want to add some scenario in JS which if $test1 exists, it will show some coding in JavaScript. I have drafted some code as follow and it doesn't work. What may it cause?

```
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            myChart.setXMLData("
            "<categories>" +
                "<category label='1'/>" +
                "<category label='2'/>" +
            "</categories>" +
            if($test1['transactions_tmp']) {
            "<dataset>" +
                "<set value='147400'/>" +
                "<set value='189100'/>" +
            "</dataset>" +
            }
            "</chart>");
        // -->
        </script>
```

Comment: You still have the XML comment start block in there: `<!--` on the first line

Comment: ^ point 1, point 2 -> PHP variables are not accessible in HTML or javascript unless you are using templating. means generating the above code in php i.e `echo jsCodeWIthPHPVariable;`

Comment: I didn't catch your answer, but I think you should do it with Ajax

Comment: @HGF Yes, I have to embed also the xml in JS

Comment: @Kermani As I am using an add-on, I have to embed xml under JS. While for my case, I still have to pass the parameter from PHP defined to control whether I need the xml code case by case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            myChart.setXMLData(
            "<categories>" +
                "<category label='1'/>" +
                "<category label='2'/>" +
            "</categories>" +
            "<?php if($test1['transactions_tmp']) { ?>" +
            "<dataset>" +
                "<set value='147400'/>" +
                "<set value='189100'/>" +
            "</dataset>" +
            "<?php } ?>" +
            "</chart>");

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried but fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            myChart.setXMLData("
            "<categories>" +
                "<category label='1'/>" +
                "<category label='2'/>" +
            "</categories>" +
            if($test1['transactions_tmp']) {
            "<dataset>" +
                "<set value='147400'/>" +
                "<set value='189100'/>" +
            "</dataset>" +
            }
            "</chart>");
        // -->
        </script>
```

this code is javasscript, if you wanna insert code php between javascript and php, you shoult use tag

`<?php samp_code_php;  ?>`

replace `if($test1['transactions_tmp']){` to `<?php if($test1['transactions_tmp']){ ?>`
      and `}` to `< ?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd give it a shot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myChart.setXMLData(
    "<categories>" +
        "<category label='1'/>" +
        "<category label='2'/>" +
    "</categories><?php if($test1['transactions_tmp']) { echo '<dataset><set value=\'147400\'/><set value=\'189100\'/></dataset>';}?></chart>");
</script>
```